# Transform JSON String to Dictionary using shell without escape

Tags: python, shell, escaping, argv

I am calling a python script from the shell, with one input argument.

```
python main.py """{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}"""
```

All keys and values are strings. Once in python, I would like to convert the JSON string to a dictionary, so I have acess to the values by using the keys.

I tried the following

```
import json
import sys
dict_in = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
```

But `dict_in` would end up a string like that `{key1:value1, key2:value2}`
So it seems like I need to find a way to pass the string with quotation marks from the shell to python. I can not use escape characters since the string is provided by a different program.

Is there an elegant way to solve this?

Comment: use base64 encoding -- you won't need even quote marks

Comment: or pipe `stdout` from "another program" to `stdin` of your python script.

Comment: can you please elaborate a little bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a python 2 module which can handle such cases.

Suppose you have this string:

```
>>> str = '{foo: bar, id: 23}'
```

Then you can use `yaml` as follows:

```
>>> import yaml
>>> dict = yaml.load(str)
>>> dict
{'foo': 'bar', 'id': 23}

>>> dict['foo']
'bar'
```

Now you have what you needed.

More info (and also python 3 support and etc.) can be found here: https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation

Comment: This seems perfect, but somehow it only works in the Python IDE. I will keep on trying on monday. Will report back.

Comment: actually I tested outside and worked just fine. I gave that `str` as the first input, which is the `sys.argv[1]` and with the above code, you get the answer you want :)

Comment: Ok I figured it out. 
1) You need a space after the `:` or else you get in error. Any way to avoid that?
2) I need to call yaml.load twice  `dict_in=yaml.load(yaml.load(sys.argv[1]))` for some weird reason. First time it converts it to a string, seconde time into a dictionary

Comment: 1) Actually this is one of the few known issues that people were arguing. When I was working with this, I wrote a script to check every colon in the string and add a space after that if there wasn't, and this solved my problem. Some people have tried changing the main module too, like the one suggested [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/1104) and [this](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/2769) is another link that reported this issue.

Comment: 2) How could such thing happen? I mean, what is the initial type of `sys.argv[1]` that after `yaml.load`, it turns to string?! It must already be a string. What do you receive after the first `yaml.load`? The same string that were passed to it?

Comment: I posted my answer. Seem like `yaml.load` does not like (").

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if what you passing in is important but you can pass following and get desired output:

```
"{\"key1\":\"value1\", \"key2\":\"value2\"}"
```

or

```
'{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}'
```

Here is the code and output:

```
$cat json_convert.py 
import json
import sys
dict_in = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
print (dict_in)
$ python json_convert.py '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}'
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
```

Also what you are passing `"""{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}"""` translates to `"" + "{" + key1 + ":" + value1 + ", " +  + key2 + ":" + value2 + "}" + ""` if you are asking `bash`, if you were calling the function with that as a argument from the `python` itself you would get the desired results.

So really goes down to what you are calling it from.

If you still like quotes go ahead and pass `"""{"'"key1"'":"'"value1"'", "'"key2"'":"'"value2"'"}"""` to get desired result :)

Comment: That works, but you are using escape characters, which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: He isn't in the second version.

Comment: @valenzio check out the 2nd approach :)

Comment: oh sorry did not see that, but that also does not work, same result as with the triple quotes.

Answer (score 0):

use either:

```
$ your_other_program | python main.py
```

to send the output of the other program to python, or use `base64.b64encode(json.dumps(blah))` and you'll get pretty code like

> 'eyJtQXV0b21hdGljVGVzdExpc3QiOiBbeyJtWSI6IDguMTE0MTA1LCAibU5hbWUiOiAiYWNjZWxlcmF0b3JFbnRpdHkiLCAibVRlc3RTdGF0dXMiOiB0cnVlLCAibVgiOiAzLjgwNDM1MTgsICJtWiI6IC0zLjM4OTU3MjF9LCB7Im1OYW1lIjogImJhcm9tZXRlckVudGl0eSIsICJtVmFsdWUiOiAwLCAibVRlc3RTdGF0dXMiOiBmYWxzZX1dLCAibUF1dG9tYXRpY1Rlc3RDb21wbGV0ZWQiOiB0cnVlfQ=='

to put in the command line, and then decode it back from `base64` into JSON.

Or, even better, use:

```
$ your_other_program >output_file.tmp
$ python main.py < output_file.tmp
$ rm output_file.tmp
```

Comment: interesting, I will give it a try on Monday, since I am not in charge of the other_program (it is not in python)

Comment: @valenzio why don't you use a file??

Comment: The Json string is saved in a seperate Database, so it would be nice if I could just use that string. Worst case my service layer could create a file with the info.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is what is my test script:

```
print("original sys.argv output\n" + (sys.argv[1]))
string_temp=(yaml.load(sys.argv[1]))
print ("first transformation\n" +string_temp)
string_temp=string_temp.replace(":",": ")

dict_in=yaml.load(string_temp)
print("This is the dictionary")
print(dict_in)
```

This is what I type into the console

```
python test_script.py """{foo:bar, id:23}"""
```

And This is the output

```
original sys.argv output
"{foo:bar, id:23}"
first transformation
{foo:bar, id:23}
This is the dictionary
{'foo': 'bar', 'id': 23}
```

This only workds if I use tripple quotes ("""). If I use (") or (') to define the input string I get an error.

Alternatively one can remove the (") from the `sys.argv[1]`

```
print("original sys.argv output\n" + (sys.argv[1]))
string_temp=(sys.argv[1])[1:-1]
print ("first transformation\n" +string_temp)
string_temp=string_temp.replace(":",": ")

dict_in=yaml.load(string_temp)
print("This is the dictionary")
print(dict_in)
```